# Analysis of Running Times

Tags: algorithm, for-loop, big-o, nested-loops, analysis

I need to give the running times for the following for loops (in big-Oh notation):

1. `sum = 0
   for i = 1 to n do
       for j = 1 to i do
           sum++`
2. `sum = 0
   for i = 1 to n do
       for j = 1 to i^3 do
           for k = 1 to j do
               sum++`
3. `sum = 0
   for i = 1 to n do
       for j = 1 to i^2 do
           if (j (mod i) = 0) then
               for k = 1 to j do
                   sum++`

Any help would be greatly appreciated, especially if you could explain how you got to the answer so that i can understand it too.

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: In hindsight I should probably mention that these are the few that I was unable to figure out with my textbook and notes, the rest I was able to solve.

Comment: What about reading some book on algorithmic complexity first, before asking something here?

Comment: Can you show and explain what you came up with for each?

Answer (score 0):

So I just started a class with very similar material so I may not have this spot on. The general idea that I have is that run time is basically based on the number of loops within the given program.

So for instance lets take your problems #1

```
sum = 0
for i = 1 to n do
    for j = 1 to i do
        sum++
```

Since its 2 nested for loops the run time grows exponentially and since you drop the lesser order terms (the sum++ would add time but it is negligible) thus leaving you with a run time of N^2.

To go a step further take this program

```
sum = 0
for i = 1 to n do
    for j = 1 to i do
        sum++
sum2 = 0
for i = 1 to n do
    for j = 1 to i do
        sum2++
```

Since it is 2 for loops back to back the running time should be 2N^2

Hope this was helpful =D